# Sum of alternating series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Looking to find the sum of the following series:

$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)3^n}$$

It converges due to the Alternating Series Test.

Prior attempts had me isolating the numerator and the $3^n$ in one fraction, and using a geometric series. However, this proved fruitless since it left the other part of the fraction with a denominator that implies divergence. I am looking to help a calculus student who turned to me for advice, but I myself have not been worked with converging series in almost a decade, and so I'm not as quick with the material as I used to be.

Comment: Recall the series for $\arctan x$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that for $|t|\lt 1$ we have 
$$\frac{1}{1+t^2}=1-t^2+t^4-t^6+\cdots.$$
Integrating term by term from $0$ to $x$ we get
$$\arctan x=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{x^7}{7}+\cdots.$$
Comparing with our given series, we see that in our given series the first term is missing. Note also that 
$$\frac{1}{3^n}=\sqrt{3}\frac{1}{(\sqrt 3)^{2n+1}}.$$
Now put things together. You will find that our series has sum a close relative of $\arctan(1/\sqrt{3})$. Recall this is $\frac{\pi}{6}$.

Answer (score 3):

To do this directly from geometric series--in case you don't immediately recall that ${1\over 1+x^2}$ has $\arctan(x)$ as an elementary anti-derivative--you can do

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n}={1\over 1-x^2},\quad |x|<1$$

This will eventually flip to arctan because of the change of variables $x\mapsto ix$, which flips ${1\over 1-x^2}\mapsto {1\over 1+x^2}$.

Then integrate both sides

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty {1\over 2n+1}x^{2n+1}=\int_0^x{dt\over 1-t^2}$$

using partial fractions you get this is ${1\over 2}\log\left({1+x\over 1-x}\right)+C$, choosing the initial term to be $0$ as in the integral gives just ${1\over 2}\log\left({1+x\over 1-x}\right)$.

Then plugging in $x={i\over \sqrt{3}}$ which clearly has $|x|<1$ gives

$${i\over\sqrt{3}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty {(-1)^{n}\over (2n+1)3^{n}}$$

Reducing gives

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty {(-1)^n\over (2n+1)3^n}={\sqrt{3}\over 2i}\log\left({1+{i\over \sqrt{3}}\over 1-{i\over \sqrt{3}}}\right)$$

Taking out the initial $n=0$ term gives

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {(-1)^n\over (2n+1)3^n}=\sqrt{3}\cdot\underbrace{{1\over 2i}\log\left({1+{i\over \sqrt{3}}\over 1-{i\over \sqrt{3}}}\right)}_{\text{this is an arctan}}-1$$

Finally we note that $\arctan x = {1\over 2i}\log\left({1+ix\over 1-ix}\right)$, which leaves us with $\sqrt{3}\arctan\left({1\over\sqrt 3}\right)-1={\pi\over 2\sqrt{3}}-1$

Answer (score 1):

To find the sum consider the series

> $$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^{2n} = \frac{1}{1-x^2} $$

Integrate both sides from zero to $x$ and then substitute $x=i/\sqrt{3}$ and simplify.

**Notes:** To evaluate the integral just use the change of variables $ t=\sin(u) $ which gives

> $$ I = \int_{0}^{x} \frac{dt}{1-t^2} = \int_{0}^{\arcsin(x)}\sec(u)du=\dots\,. $$

You need the integral

> $$ \int \sec(u)du = \ln(\sec(x)+\tan(x)). $$

Comment: This gives a ${1\over 9}$ style sum and doesn't alternate.

Comment: @AdamHughes: you need go integrate it first. Read my ansser carefully.

Comment: Even after you integrate you get a term like $x^{2n+1}$ with $x=-{1\over 3}$ you get $\left({-1\over 3}\right)^{2n}\cdot {-1\over 3}$ which doesn't alternate, it's just all negative terms, since the $(-1)$ gets raised to always an odd power.

Comment: @AdamHughes: it is corrected. I was answering from my iphone. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: no problem. :-) I know **exactly** how that goes.